# Hartl Tutorial Chapter 10: param micropost not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am currently between Listing 10.32 and 10.33 of this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#sec-manipulating_microposts

And I have ran into a problem while running the test. The output is as follows:

```
Failures:

  1) Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information should not create a micropost
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param not found: micropost
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:23:in `micropost_params'
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:8:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information error messages 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Post" }
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param not found: micropost
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:23:in `micropost_params'
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:8:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:20:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Micropost pages micropost creation with valid information should create a micropost
     Failure/Error: before { fill_in 'micropost_content', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "micropost_content"
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.56491 seconds
3 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:15 # Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information should not create a micropost
rspec ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:21 # Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information error messages 
rspec ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:28 # Micropost pages micropost creation with valid information should create a micropost
```

And here is the currently failing test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Micropost pages" do

    subject { page }

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { sign_in user }

    describe "micropost creation" do
        before { visit root_path }

        describe "with invalid information" do

            it "should not create a micropost" do
                expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
            end

            describe "error messages" do
                before { click_button "Post" }
                it { should have_content('error') }
            end
        end

        describe "with valid information" do

            before { fill_in 'micropost_content', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
            it "should create a micropost" do
                expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(1)
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Which means the @micropost variable is clearly not being set, but it is set in the static pages controller. I have checked for a while now do discover differences from the tutorial, but have not succeeded in finding any.

The git repository is here: https://github.com/afuhrtrumpet/sample_app/tree/user-microposts

Does anyone see this issue?

Comment: `micropost_pages_spec.rb` now exists in the github repository. I will also include it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a missing '=' sign here:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
```